# How bright is the area around a black hole over its lifetime?

Tags: visible-light, cosmology, black-holes

[I love Vsauce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJB7gbjiJKw)

So naturally I began to think what anybody *normal person* (I have no friends) would think in this situation. Can light *orbit*  a black hole. Apparently it can and its called a photon-sphere and this is what I mean by *around* a black hole so don't go talking to me about quasars. What is the apparent magnitude of someone in the photon sphere facing against the direction of the photons. Now I hope I am right in assuming that a black hole should capture more and more photons in the sphere along the course of its life (although, I do think, in a non-physical but logical sense, that if it captures more photons it may also capture more mass making the gravity stronger so that the area where the photon sphere should be would be further out so the current photons in the sphere would just get pulled (not 'sucked' *#I'mPC (physically correct)* in).

Now if you want to be specific , I am not picky as to what black hole you use (unless you take advantage of this and pick some black hole that disappeared in 2 seconds or something (it's a big universe that I don't know of) and the best way of displaying the answer (that I can think of) is by showing a graph with the y-axis being the AM and the X-axis being the life of your chosen black hole.

Also who's up for emojis d: ? (not serious but it would be cool)

*cough* NGC 4889 *cough*

Comment: Only non-spinning black holes can have a photon sphere, and as Wikipedia says, the orbits of captured photons are rarely stable, so I don't think you'll get much photon accumulation happening. With spinning BHs, things are more complicated. There are a couple of circular orbits in the equatorial plane, but some non-flat orbits are also possible. I have no idea if that helps or hinders accumulation of photons.

Comment: Then again,the sheer quantity of photons could be enough. Like how 100000000K creates Brownian noise